# Correct configuration for devise_ldap_authenticatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap

I'm having some connectivity issues with my Rails app (using Devise + Devise LDAP Authenticatable) and the Active Directory server I'm attempting to communicate with.

I've been able to successfully perform a bind and search with `ldapsearch` using the following command:

`ldapsearch -H ldap://ad.example.com:389 -b "ou=dept,ou=Users,ou=company,dc=example,dc=com" -D "me@example.com" -W "&(objectClass=organizationalPerson)(objectClass=Person))" mail`

Since that works, I'm assuming I have an issue with my devise_ldap_authenticatable configuration, which looks like:

```
development: 
  host: ad.example.com
  port: 389
  attribute: mail
  base: ou=dept,ou=Users,ou=company,dc=example,dc=com
  objectClass: organizationalPerson
  objectClass: Person
  ssl: false
```

Using Wireshark I was able to capture traffic from both the successful bind/search (CLI) and the failed bind/search (Rails). The successful bind correctly sends the email address as part of the `bindRequest` (`LDAPMessage bindRequest(1) "me@example.com" simple`) but the `bindRequest` from the Rails app looks like `LDAPMessage bindRequest(1) "<ROOT>" simple`

Is anyone able to spot an obvious issue with my config? Can anyone translate my `ldapsearch` command into a proper YAML config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had played around with this `Devise.rb` config option previously, but must have done something incorrect.

Adding the following to `Devise.rb` seems to have resolved my bind issue:

```
config.ldap_auth_username_builder = Proc.new() { |attribute, login, ldap| login }
```

Comment: thanks man! I was fighting with this gem for 3 days and this simple line helps me :)