# rails devise ldap_authentication cannot find user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ldap

I am trying to use thise gem according base documentation (https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable)

this is my devise.rb config

```
     # ==> LDAP Configuration 

   config.ldap_logger = true
   config.ldap_create_user = true
   config.ldap_config = "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml"
```

and this is my ldap.yml

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS

  allow_unauthenticated_bind: true
  group_base: ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com
  ## Requires config.ldap_check_group_membership in devise.rb be true
  # Can have multiple values, must match all to be authorized
  required_groups:
    # If only a group name is given, membership will be checked against "uniqueMember"
    - cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com
    - cn=users,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com
    # If an array is given, the first element will be the attribute to check against, the second the group name
    - ["moreMembers", "cn=users,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com"]
  ## Requires config.ldap_check_attributes in devise.rb to be true
  ## Can have multiple attributes and values, must match all to be authorized
  require_attribute:
    objectClass: inetOrgPerson
    authorizationRole: postsAdmin

## Environment

development:
  host: myACtiveDirectory.server
  port: 389
  attribute: userPrincipalName
  base: dc=mycompanydomain,dc=com
  admin_user: cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com
  admin_password: admin_password
  ssl: false
  # <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

when I try to login, what I want to achieve is login with email and pass and if user is not present in local DB, create record.
In logs I see that LDAP cannot find user according userPrincipalName and it is always twice (is it trying twice before it fails?)

```
LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: userPrincipalName=mirob@mycompanydomain.com
  LDAP: LDAP search for login: userPrincipalName=mirob@mycompanydomain.com
  LDAP: LDAP search yielded 0 matches
  LDAP: Authorizing user userPrincipalName=mirob@mycompanydomain.com,dc=mycompanydomain,dc=com
  LDAP: Not authorized because not authenticated.
  LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: userPrincipalName=mirob@mycompanydomain.com
  LDAP: LDAP search for login: userPrincipalName=mirob@mycompanydomain.com
  LDAP: LDAP search yielded 0 matches
  LDAP: Authorizing user userPrincipalName=mirob@mycompanydomain.com,dc=mycompanydomain,dc=com
  LDAP: Not authorized because not authenticated.
```

When I use script from this question to test (I changed sAMAccountName to principal name and I dont merge username with domain) I can login to LDAP so connection is working
[Ldap is not working with Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705048/ldap-is-not-working-with-devise/35774277)

any idea what is wrong with my devise ldap setup?

EDIT:
ok I found that ldap_authenticable is searching for DN what in my case (Active Directory setup) is CN=Complete Name,CN=Users,CN=mydomain,CN=com
The question is how can I search for email instead of Complete Name as I cant update AD for all users to put email into name field?

Answer (score 0):

ok I found this answer and it helped me
[Correct configuration for devise_ldap_authenticatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371812/correct-configuration-for-devise-ldap-authenticatable/17424862#17424862)

I just needed to add this line to devise.rb and I can simple authenticate according to userPrincipalName

```
config.ldap_auth_username_builder = Proc.new() {|attribute, login, ldap| login}
```