# Rails 7 auth with devise + devise_ldap_authenticatable and roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap, ruby-on-rails-7

I wrote an app in Rails 7 + [devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) + [devise_ldap_authenticatable](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable)

My goal would be get roles from Active Directory.

My LDAP Configuration in devise.rb

```rb
  # ==> LDAP Configuration
  config.ldap_logger = true
  config.ldap_create_user = true
  config.ldap_update_password = false
  config.ldap_config = "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml"
  # config.ldap_check_group_membership = false
  # config.ldap_check_group_membership_without_admin = false
  # config.ldap_check_attributes = false
  # config.ldap_check_attributes_presence = false
  config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true
  # config.ldap_ad_group_check = false

  # Sin esta linea trata de buscar por mail en vez de por el atributo definido en
  # config.ldap_config = "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml"
  # 
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121543/rails-devise-ldap-authentication-cannot-find-user
  #
  config.ldap_auth_username_builder = Proc.new() {|attribute, login, ldap| login}
```

My ldap.yml

```yaml
## Authorizations
# Uncomment out the merging for each environment that you'd like to include.
# You can also just copy and paste the tree (do not include the "authorizations") to each
# environment if you need something different per environment.
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
  allow_unauthenticated_bind: false
  ### group_base: ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com
  ## Requires config.ldap_check_group_membership in devise.rb be true
  # Can have multiple values, must match all to be authorized
  required_groups:
    # If only a group name is given, membership will be checked against "uniqueMember"
    ### - cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com
    ### - cn=users,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com
    # If an array is given, the first element will be the attribute to check against, the second the group name
    ### - ["moreMembers", "cn=users,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com"]
  ## Requires config.ldap_check_attributes in devise.rb to be true
  ## Can have multiple attributes and values, must match all to be authorized
  require_attribute:
    ### objectClass: inetOrgPerson
    ### authorizationRole: postsAdmin
  ## Requires config.ldap_check_attributes_presence in devise.rb to be true
  ## Can have multiple attributes set to true or false to check presence, all must match all to be authorized
  require_attribute_presence:
    ### mail: true
    ### telephoneNumber: true
    ### serviceAccount: false

## Environment

development:
  host: 13.0.0.1
  port: 389
  attribute: userPrincipalName
  base: ou=Users,ou=first,dc=mydomain,dc=net
  admin_user: cn=Admin,ou=Users,ou=first,dc=mydomain,dc=net
  admin_password: ***********
  ssl: false
  # <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

My User schema

```rb
t.string   "email",                                    default: "",    null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",                       default: ""
t.string   "role",                                     default: ""
```

My User model

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :ldap_authenticatable
end
```

What would be a good aproach to get roles from Active Directory?

I have this aproach... (DISCLAIMER: PSEUDOCODE)

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :ldap_authenticatable

  before_save :get_role_from_ldap

  def get_role_from_ldap
    self.role = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.  <<< get_ldap_groups or what ever >>>

    or even better

    role = 'user'

    roles = self.ldap_groups
    if roles.include?('moderator')
      role = 'moderator'
    if roles.include?('admin')
      role = 'role'

    self.role = role

  end
end
```

But

- I don't know what to use to get those groups
- I don't know how to chosse between those groups

Any suggestion?

Why ldap_groups method from **devise_ldap_authenticatable/model.rb** always return an empty array?